# Why Does Using top or bottom Reduce the Element's Height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position an icon responsively which is part of a plugin in WordPress.

Using `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` works to position the icon further down the page, but `top` and `bottom` above `10px` seems to reduce the height of the icon when used in conjunction with `position: relative;`

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    #a2a_share_save_widget-3 {
        position: relative !important;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: 95%;
        margin-left: -37px;
        background-color: transparent! important;
        color: transparent! important;
    }
}
```

If I reduce `top` to `10px`, the icon goes back to full height again.

Html:

```
<div id="a2a_share_save_widget- 3" class="widget widget_a2a_share_save_widget">
    <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 addtoany_list">
        <a class="a2a_dd a2a_counter addtoany_share_save addtoany_share" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to apply `top` or  `bottom` to adjust position, not icon height.

Mobile page [here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: It looks like it's because of the property `overflow: hidden` that is given to `section, footer`. The element is technically overflowing and therefore parts of it are hidden.

Comment: Ah, so how so I fix it?

Comment: remove that property or have your `section` take up at least X amount of space to accomodate your share widget

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to override with css?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with regards to the share widget's height being reduced. The issue is that `overflow: hidden` is given to its ancestor `section` - the share widget is technically overflowing and parts of it are hidden.

So to solve this, either remove/override the property `overflow: hidden` from `section`

```
#content section {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

or have the widget's container take X amount of minimum height

```
div#main {
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

I imagine you want to increase specificity as these examples are generic terms and you are using a wordpress theme

Comment: Thanks. Applied `#content section {
    overflow: visible;`} and it worked to show whole icon but now a large gap has opened between my picture and bottom of the page and on the right.

Comment: I do not see any gap. This is all the help I can provide as I cannot see the issue related to the gap. If the wordpress theme relies on the use of `overflow:hidden`, you can come up with new strategies. My explanation should suffice to provide you with the knowledge on why `top` & `bottom` creates the illusion of reducing the element's `height`. Good luck

Comment: Not sure how to find widget container as `view-source` search located only the above html with widget id as listed above. Reduced height of element ID to 0px but that just hides the icon altogether.